# Run PHP script from CLI and pass parameters

Tags: php, parameters, command-line-interface

I have a PHP script check.php with a function

```
<?php
function checkValues($arg1, $arg2){

...

}
?>
```

How can I pass parameter to the function through the Linux command line and run the script?

Comment: you may want to read http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run PHP:

`php /my/script.php arg1 arg2`

Then in your PHP file:

```
<?php
// It's 0 based, but arg1 will be at index 1!
var_dump($argv);
```

Answer (score 3):

When running a script from the command line, all parameters passed in after the file name e.g. `php my-script.php 123`will be in a PHP array called `$argv`.

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> string(13) "my-script.php"
    [1]=> int(3) 123
}
```